# hide payment gateway on specific shipping method

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a shipping method which is called " SMSA EXPRESS - CASH ON DELIVERY " .. so when customer chooses this shipping method he should see the cash on delivery option for the payment and not the other options, which are the payments gateways ..
I tried to use this code but it didn't work

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'bbloomer_gateway_disable_shipping_326' );
  
function bbloomer_gateway_disable_shipping_326( $available_gateways ) {
     
   if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        
      $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
        
      $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];
        
      if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'SMSA_EXPRESS_-_CASH_ON_DELIVERY' ) ) {
         unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
      }
        
   }
     
   return $available_gateways;
     
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you debug that filter is calling or not? and if does then did you check this conditional statement if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'SMSA_EXPRESS_-_CASH_ON_DELIVERY' ) ) {

Comment: shouldn't unset be called on the other methods? you've put it on cod? or am I missing something?